# RedirectToAction not calling action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Why is it that the Index action is not calling Foo on the RedirectToAction? I put a breakpoint and it doesn't seem to be hitting this action. It should be noted that my modelstate is valid so that is not the issue.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Home model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        TempData["model"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("Foo");
    }

    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        Home model = (Home)TempData["model"];
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: ModelState.IsValid? put a break point there and see expression.

Comment: @BeiBeiZHU the breakpoint isn't called...not hit...the modelstate is valid it goes to the return

Comment: Take sure you are doing anything right. Here is Msdn help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: @Drogba go to which return? return view or return RedirecToAction?  BTW, tempData i remember only can store string, cant store object, you try to serialize it first.

Comment: @BeiBei ZHU no needs to serialize. Tempdata uses TempDataDictionary.    Does the View that you are trying to return actually exist?

Comment: unrelated to your issue, but use `nameof(Foo)` instead of hardcoding the action name as `"Foo"` :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Same controller Alternatively if you don't want a redirect
Just return view. because I checked your code in my Demo Application and try to reproduce your issue. but Your code working fine

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Home model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        TempData["model"] = model;
        return View("Foo");
    }
```

If it is not working then you may check your routes and make sure there are no special Routes define that could make things break. 
 Or inside your `Global.asax` add this method and debug .

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
}
```